# read.csv() not working on shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am developing a shiny application where my .csv files have to be loaded using read.csv(). read.csv() commands are working fine on console, but whenever I run my app it is throwing:

> object "rainfall" not found error

The following are my code snippets

**global.R**

```
get.rain.ds<-function(){
read.csv("./Data/rainfall_dataset.csv",skip=1,nrows=32,header = TRUE)
}
```

**server.R**

```
source("./global.R")
rainfall<-get.rain.ds()
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: One reason could be that `Data` folder is not there in your shiny folder. Let's re-verify if you have a folder by this name and `rainfall_dataset.csv` is present inside that.